# Powershell Credentials Request Window Size

Tags: powershell

Powershell Noob here.

I have a basic Powershell script that requests user's credentials and then starts MMC programs for remote administration (example: dsa.msc). No issues with the script.

However, I am not happy with the size of the "Windows Powershell Credentials Request" window. I am using `Get-Credential "$env:USERDNSDOMAIN\"` but our domain name is pretty long.

What I would like:

1. (Preferred) Have the the domain name gathered in the script ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN) and the when the user is prompted for credentials; the username field will be empty and the user will only need to type their AD username. OR
2. Have the credentials be collected WITHIN the powershell window so there is enough room

Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the default modal dialog/UI in Windows. If you want this control, you can write your own Winfomr/WPF GUI. deploy that for users to execute.

If you have not done this, use this free tool (though WinForm only - for now)...

[Online Powershell Form Designer](https://poshgui.com)

...for your first effort at GUI design, but read up on GUI design (Winform and WPF) to know what this is about and the other steps you are going to need to do, to get it to do anything.

Youtube - 
['PowerShell gui design'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20gui%20design)

As for your two bullet points. You are halfway there. Just do this:

```
Get-Credential "$env:USERDNSDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"
```

Comment: Thanks! The user will be entering a different username than their current so "$env:USERDNSDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" won't work in this scenario.

Comment: Anyway to Pre-fill the domain info in the script earlier but dialog box will only ask the user for the username? Once the user enters the elevated username, it will be used along with the domain?

Comment: They could type over whatever is there or your code could just overwrite is as well, just as you would if it were blank.